# prom-client format vs Grafana Cloud push interface

Tags: grafana, prom-client

I am new to Prometheus/Grafana world and wanna get metrics from my node.js app for which I use [prom-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prom-client) to get the metrics as given below. That works :-)

Now I wanna push them to Grafana Cloud and it seems I have the following  options

1. https://influx-prod-01-eu-west-0.grafana.net/api/v1/push/influx/write
   (using influxdb line format)
2. https://prometheus-prod-01-eu-west-0.grafana.net/api/prom/push
   (using a to me not known format - it's seems not to accept the one from prom-client as text or json it appears accprding to my tests)

So I wonder if anybody knows the format in which I need to push metrics to endpoint 2. or how I can transform the format from prom-client to influxdb line format

Cheers
Tom

```
# HELP process_cpu_user_seconds_total Total user CPU time spent in seconds.
# TYPE process_cpu_user_seconds_total counter
process_cpu_user_seconds_total 0.391

# HELP process_cpu_system_seconds_total Total system CPU time spent in seconds.
# TYPE process_cpu_system_seconds_total counter
process_cpu_system_seconds_total 0.157

# HELP process_cpu_seconds_total Total user and system CPU time spent in seconds.
# TYPE process_cpu_seconds_total counter
process_cpu_seconds_total 0.548

# HELP process_start_time_seconds Start time of the process since unix epoch in seconds.
# TYPE process_start_time_seconds gauge
process_start_time_seconds 1666774055

# HELP process_resident_memory_bytes Resident memory size in bytes.
# TYPE process_resident_memory_bytes gauge
process_resident_memory_bytes 151728128

# HELP nodejs_eventloop_lag_seconds Lag of event loop in seconds.
# TYPE nodejs_eventloop_lag_seconds gauge
nodejs_eventloop_lag_seconds 0

# HELP nodejs_eventloop_lag_min_seconds The minimum recorded event loop delay.
# TYPE nodejs_eventloop_lag_min_seconds gauge
nodejs_eventloop_lag_min_seconds 0.010862592

# HELP nodejs_eventloop_lag_max_seconds The maximum recorded event loop delay.
# TYPE nodejs_eventloop_lag_max_seconds gauge
nodejs_eventloop_lag_max_seconds 0.400556031

# HELP nodejs_eventloop_lag_mean_seconds The mean of the recorded event loop delays.
# TYPE nodejs_eventloop_lag_mean_seconds gauge
nodejs_eventloop_lag_mean_seconds 0.018597868116504854

# HELP nodejs_eventloop_lag_stddev_seconds The standard deviation of the recorded event loop delays.
# TYPE nodejs_eventloop_lag_stddev_seconds gauge
nodejs_eventloop_lag_stddev_seconds 0.02698809788282721

# HELP nodejs_eventloop_lag_p50_seconds The 50th percentile of the recorded event loop delays.
# TYPE nodejs_eventloop_lag_p50_seconds gauge
nodejs_eventloop_lag_p50_seconds 0.015605759

# HELP nodejs_eventloop_lag_p90_seconds The 90th percentile of the recorded event loop delays.
# TYPE nodejs_eventloop_lag_p90_seconds gauge
nodejs_eventloop_lag_p90_seconds 0.020840447

# HELP nodejs_eventloop_lag_p99_seconds The 99th percentile of the recorded event loop delays.
# TYPE nodejs_eventloop_lag_p99_seconds gauge
nodejs_eventloop_lag_p99_seconds 0.034930687

# HELP nodejs_active_resources Number of active resources that are currently keeping the event loop alive, grouped by async resource type.
# TYPE nodejs_active_resources gauge
nodejs_active_resources{type="TTYWrap"} 3
nodejs_active_resources{type="TCPSocketWrap"} 2
nodejs_active_resources{type="TCPServerWrap"} 1
nodejs_active_resources{type="Timeout"} 2
nodejs_active_resources{type="Immediate"} 1

# HELP nodejs_active_resources_total Total number of active resources.
# TYPE nodejs_active_resources_total gauge
nodejs_active_resources_total 9

# HELP nodejs_active_handles Number of active libuv handles grouped by handle type. Every handle type is C++ class name.
# TYPE nodejs_active_handles gauge
nodejs_active_handles{type="WriteStream"} 2
nodejs_active_handles{type="ReadStream"} 1
nodejs_active_handles{type="Socket"} 2
nodejs_active_handles{type="Server"} 1

# HELP nodejs_active_handles_total Total number of active handles.
# TYPE nodejs_active_handles_total gauge
nodejs_active_handles_total 6

# HELP nodejs_active_requests Number of active libuv requests grouped by request type. Every request type is C++ class name.
# TYPE nodejs_active_requests gauge

# HELP nodejs_active_requests_total Total number of active requests.
# TYPE nodejs_active_requests_total gauge
nodejs_active_requests_total 0

# HELP nodejs_heap_size_total_bytes Process heap size from Node.js in bytes.
# TYPE nodejs_heap_size_total_bytes gauge
nodejs_heap_size_total_bytes 110747648

# HELP nodejs_heap_size_used_bytes Process heap size used from Node.js in bytes.
# TYPE nodejs_heap_size_used_bytes gauge
nodejs_heap_size_used_bytes 85839336

# HELP nodejs_external_memory_bytes Node.js external memory size in bytes.
# TYPE nodejs_external_memory_bytes gauge
nodejs_external_memory_bytes 19901895

# HELP nodejs_heap_space_size_total_bytes Process heap space size total from Node.js in bytes.
# TYPE nodejs_heap_space_size_total_bytes gauge
nodejs_heap_space_size_total_bytes{space="read_only"} 176128
nodejs_heap_space_size_total_bytes{space="old"} 65003520
nodejs_heap_space_size_total_bytes{space="code"} 2203648
nodejs_heap_space_size_total_bytes{space="map"} 3153920
nodejs_heap_space_size_total_bytes{space="large_object"} 6656000
nodejs_heap_space_size_total_bytes{space="code_large_object"} 0
nodejs_heap_space_size_total_bytes{space="new_large_object"} 0
nodejs_heap_space_size_total_bytes{space="new"} 33554432

# HELP nodejs_heap_space_size_used_bytes Process heap space size used from Node.js in bytes.
# TYPE nodejs_heap_space_size_used_bytes gauge
nodejs_heap_space_size_used_bytes{space="read_only"} 170944
nodejs_heap_space_size_used_bytes{space="old"} 63718088
nodejs_heap_space_size_used_bytes{space="code"} 2052736
nodejs_heap_space_size_used_bytes{space="map"} 3096944
nodejs_heap_space_size_used_bytes{space="large_object"} 6507048
nodejs_heap_space_size_used_bytes{space="code_large_object"} 0
nodejs_heap_space_size_used_bytes{space="new_large_object"} 0
nodejs_heap_space_size_used_bytes{space="new"} 10302016

# HELP nodejs_heap_space_size_available_bytes Process heap space size available from Node.js in bytes.
# TYPE nodejs_heap_space_size_available_bytes gauge
nodejs_heap_space_size_available_bytes{space="read_only"} 0
nodejs_heap_space_size_available_bytes{space="old"} 118272
nodejs_heap_space_size_available_bytes{space="code"} 3456
nodejs_heap_space_size_available_bytes{space="map"} 0
nodejs_heap_space_size_available_bytes{space="large_object"} 0
nodejs_heap_space_size_available_bytes{space="code_large_object"} 0
nodejs_heap_space_size_available_bytes{space="new_large_object"} 16497152
nodejs_heap_space_size_available_bytes{space="new"} 6195136

# HELP nodejs_version_info Node.js version info.
# TYPE nodejs_version_info gauge
nodejs_version_info{version="v16.17.0",major="16",minor="17",patch="0"} 1

# HELP nodejs_gc_duration_seconds Garbage collection duration by kind, one of major, minor, incremental or weakcb.
# TYPE nodejs_gc_duration_seconds histogram
nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.001",kind="minor"} 0
nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.01",kind="minor"} 1
nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.1",kind="minor"} 1
nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_bucket{le="1",kind="minor"} 1
nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_bucket{le="2",kind="minor"} 1
nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_bucket{le="5",kind="minor"} 1
nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_bucket{le="+Inf",kind="minor"} 1
nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_sum{kind="minor"} 0.004263499975204468
nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_count{kind="minor"} 1
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?